The difference between typeof and typeis in Gosu
My coworker and I have tried running tests but they haven't been conclusive.  The question is, what is the difference between typeof and typeis in the Gosu language?  Examples:
typeis:
if(some_obj typeis some_class) { do xyz }
typeof:
if(typeof some_obj == some_class) { do abc }
Can anyone settle our discussion?  We are under the impression that one of these keywords checks for if an object is a member of a class and any of its children vs. checking if an object is a member of a class, period (ie, not also its children).

Both operators are used to retrieve or test an item’s type.

The typeof operator retrieves the run-time type of an item.
The typeis operator tests the type of an item.

Use the typeof operator to retrieve the run-time type of a data item. Comparing the retrieved type to a subtype of the retrieved type evaluates to false
A typeis expression tests the type of an object. If the object is of either the tested type or a subtype of the tested type, the expression evaluates to true.

it should also be stated that typeis has the additional benefit of casting the object to that type, if it returns true such at the local variable is now of that type.
say you are iterating over a set of coverages
coverages.each(\cov -> {
    if (cov typeis CoverageA) {
      cov.PropertyOnCoverageA = "this works"
    } else {
      cov.PropertyOnCoverageB = "this doesn't work"
    }
})

This means you do not need to do (cov as CoverageA).PropertyOnCoverageA since the typeis already provided the cast.
